# Problem installing sqlite3-ruby!

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sqlite3-ruby

I'm having issues installing the sqlite3-ruby gem on crunchbang linux.  After googling the past few hours and following several people with the same problem, I still haven't gotten it to work.

Here is what I see after trying a 'sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby'

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... no
sqlite3-ruby only supports sqlite3 versions 3.6.16+, please upgrade!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Next I ran across this page;
http://groups.google.com/group/sqlite3-ruby/browse_thread/thread/f22d098b561c48af/6e754f7b2fc3cd75?#6e754f7b2fc3cd75

I downloaded sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.0.1.tar.gz and issued the following commands:

tar zxvf sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.0.1.tar.gz
cd cd sqlite-3.7.0.1
mkdir $HOME/sqlite
./configure --prefix=$HOME/sqlite
make && make install
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/sqlite

However, I still get the exact same error.  I've used 'sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev' but I still get the exact same error.

Any advice?

And as a small aside, how come when I use 'sudo apt-get install sqlite3', it grabs 3.5.9 instead of the 3.7.0.1 I manually downloaded?

Answer (score 15):

Install a lower version of sqlite3-ruby should resolve your problem:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby --version=1.2.5
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to extconf.rb picking up your old 3.5.9 library when testing for functions before putting together the Makefile.

One solution to cut this short is to apt-get remove sqlite3 and retry

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/sqlite
```

This may save you from incompatibilities if you want to use sqlite3 command line binary.

Another solution is to copy your new ~/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a into the build directory of your gem (see gem env, something like gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3) and retry

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

The test should pick up your new library now and install fine.

Answer (score 2):

Per the sqlite3-ruby (now named sqlite3) README.rdoc, you can use the following method to direct to the correct libraries:

> If you have sqlite3 installed in a non-standard location, you can specify
>   the location of the include and lib
>   files by doing:
>
> `gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/opt/local/include \`
>
> --with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/local/lib

Comment: if you downloaded and installed sqlite3 from source into /usr/local this is the way to go!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Jarek's solution worked when I moved all of the files (not just `libsqlite3.a`) from `~/sqlite/lib` to `gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn, let me try to elaborate.

Ruby is adapting to the sqlite3 library by compiling petty examples and verifying if compile was successfull. This picks up the old library, which does not include the required functions.

The first solution is to remove the old library and to direct ruby to the directory you downloaded the new version to. Depending on the system you are using you have to choose the right package manager: apt-get, dpkg, yum, yast, ipkg, ... to remove the obsolete package. This makes sure your build is not picking up any old pieces. Then you have to make sure you are pointing ruby to the right directory where the new library is located with --with-sqlite3-dir option.

The second solution is a kind of a hack. It relies on C compiler picking up the files in the current directory before the others. You can use cp, mc, or any other file manager to copy the .a libraries and .h headers to the build directory. The build shoud be ok, but your sqlite3 command will still be the old one, possibly incompatible with the databases created with your new library.

HTH, Jarek

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - I simply commented out the following annoying line from ./Gemfile in the project directory to:

```
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

and did:

```
bundle install
```

script/rails server  was working fine again.  Phew!

Seems like sqlite3 is duplicated - weird

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue on OSX 10.5.8

The solutions was pretty simple:

1.- Xcode downloaded from apple dev.: xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg (require registration)
2.- Download and install macports: http://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-1.9.2-10.5-Leopard.dmg
3.- sudo port install sqlite3

And Everything was working as intended.

Hope this result useful!