# Sqlite3 error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Hey, I've recently been having trouble properly installing my Sqlite3 gem. I've already tried installing sqlite3, followed by sqlite3-ruby and I keep getting an error message. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to correct this? Here's the error message:

```
demetriuford$ gem install sqlite3-ruby 1.3.3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/demetriuford/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... no
sqlite3-ruby only supports sqlite3 versions 3.6.16+, please upgrade!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/Users/demetriuford/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
 --with-sqlite3-dir
 --without-sqlite3-dir
 --with-sqlite3-include
 --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
 --with-sqlite3-lib
 --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
 --with-sqlite3lib
 --without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/demetriuford/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/demetriuford/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '1.3.3' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Comment: Please indent the output of this error with four spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `sqlite3` gem instead.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3-ruby has changed name to sqlite3 .
i suggest to read the result of command

rvm notes

It suggest the lib you need to install for your system .

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your systems sqlite3 library, either that or use an older version of the sqlite3-ruby gem, but I recommend the former. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473214/problem-installing-sqlite3-ruby) as a possible duplicate.

Try Google'ing the [error message](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sqlite3-ruby+only+supports+sqlite3+versions+3.6.16%2B,+please+upgrade!), it's possible you're not the only person that's come across this message.

That's the first error, the second is because you're attempting to install a gem named '1.3.3', if you want to specify gem versions use the `-v` command.

The issue has nothing to do with the sqlite3-ruby library being 'renamed', sqlite3 is now just aliased to sqlite3-ruby, the latter is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

First try to install latest sqlite3 in your system via package manager (if you are in UNIX-like system) or the usual way if you on Windows.

After try installing sqlite3 gem again. If you get an error supply the following informations:

OS, OS Version, SQLite3 version, ruby version.

Best Regards,